# Data type error conversion failed varchar to int

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am storing cookies and trying to show Items in cart with help of cookie but I got this error "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'CartPID' to data type int" at sda.Fill(dt) when click on cart button. I Know CartPID is varchar but how can I overcome this error.At index[0]="CartPID" it is holding string value while I need int value which are on the index starting from One.

```
 string CookieData = Request.Cookies["CartPID"].Value.Split('=')[1];
        string[] CookieDataArray = CookieData.Split(',');
        if (CookieDataArray.Length > 0)

        {
            h5NoItems.InnerText = "MY CART (" + CookieDataArray.Length + " Items)";//to show total num of items 
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            Int64 CartTotal = 0;
            Int64 Total = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= CookieDataArray.Length; i++)//this loop will get PID and sizeID
            {
                string PID = CookieDataArray[i].ToString().Split('-')[0];
               // string SizeID = CookieDataArray[i].ToString().Split('-')[1];
                String CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
                {

                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ID='" + PID+"'", con))

                    {
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                        }

                    }
```

Comment: You don't surround numbers with single quotes in sql. But anyway you should use `SqlParameter` to avoid this problem and much worse ones.

Comment: Is your PID datatype varchar in db?

Comment: Does the `PID` _variable_ contain the string `CartPID`? That is what SQL server is telling you.

Comment: And do you know what SQL injection is? I can always edit a cookie to contain `DROP TABLE users`.

Comment: @PoonamShingrut data type is int but value in the array at 0 index is CartPID which is varchar. Others indexes contain int value.

Comment: @SalmanA string[] CookieDataArray = CookieData.Split(',') at index 0 why it holds cartpid varchar the other index are ok contains int values.

Answer (score 1):

You should never use input from the client without making sure it's safe. Use a SqlParameter when building this query so you aren't facilitating an SQL injection

```
var query = "Select  * from Products where ID = @id";
using( var command = new SqlCommand(query, con){
    command.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Varchar).Value = pid;
    .... 
}
```

If the PID is really an int use something like:

```
int pid;
if(int.TryParse(CookieDataArray[i].ToString().Split('-')[0], out pid){
// the sql command goes here SqlDbType.Int this time
}
```

Comment: I have to pass int value to the parameter but in the array at 0 index is "CartPID" which is varchar. Others indexes contain int value.

Comment: @Arslanjappa I assume you mean the value at index zero is a string, the second code block above parses that value to an integer, if it can be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ID=" + PID, con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```

or try

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Products where ID=@PID", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@PID", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters["@PID"].Value = PID;

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        sda.Fill(dt);
    }
}
```